# Would Gollum's clothes turn invisible when he wore The One Ring?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium, hobbits

We know that both Frodo and Bilbo turned 100% fully invisible when wearing The One Ring, their clothes included (as seen in Bilbo's disappearing trick at his farewell party, and Frodo's disappearance in the tavern).

Is there any indication **in Tolkien** of whether Gollum - who was related to hobbits - had the same effect (e.g. his clothes would become invisible when wearing his Precious)?

Please note that this only applies to times/situations when he wore clothes (possibly while he was still Smeagol), since it's quite possible that after multitude of years of feral living as Gollum he had no clothes.

Comment: -1 Gollum wasn't "related to" hobbits, he was a hobbit. As such he would be affected in the same way as all of the other hobbits we see wear the ring.

Comment: @NominSim - I'm looking for confirmation of that fact (or refutation) **by Tolkien**, not by analogous guess.

Comment: Confirmation that hobbits clothes are not visible when wearing the ring? Don't you have that?

Comment: @NominSim - that Gollum's (or Smeagorl's) cloths were not visible. Bilbo's and Frodo's are obvious, as the question states

Comment: @NominSim - Also, you are wrong that he was "a hobbit". To quote from SFF answer: "‘There aws long ago living by the bank of the stream a wise, cleverhanded and quietfooted family. **I guess they were of hobbit-kind, or akin to the fathers of the fathers of the hobbits**".

Comment: **"Hobbit-kind", indicates that he is of hobbit kind, meaning...a hobbit.** Further evidence is given in Appendix B of *The Return of the King*: "About this time Deagol the Stoor finds the One Ring, and is murdered by Smeagol". The Stoors are one of the three branches of hobbits. Given the fact that Gollum was a hobbit, we have to assume that the ring affected him the same way as every other hobbit we see it affect.

Comment: @NominSim - I'm not sure that Smeagol or Deagol were identified specifically as Stoors - given the timescale their relationship to hobbits of Bilbo's time could be more like our relationship to Homo Neandarthal

Comment: @HorusKol The quote in my previous comment has that specific identificaton.

Comment: ah - oops, missed that it was a quote...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Regardless of the debate on whether Smeagol was a hobbit or merely related to hobbits - I'm not sure why you would think this is species-limited.

Isildur wears the ring and becomes invisible when escaping the ambush by orcs on his journey north. It then slips off when he's in the water, and the orcs pepper him with arrows - and he was fully clothed.

The only person in the films seen to wear the ring and not become invisible is Sauron - the books aren't as explicit about that, but again they do not mention anyone having to be naked to be invisible while wearing the ring. As noted, Tom Bombadil also put on the ring and was not made invisible - while we do not find out who or what Tom is, it is fairly obvious that he is not a mortal like Isildur or the hobbits.

It could be that Sauron, as the maker of the ring, can also decide on his visibility as he might have more control on the ring's power.

Comment: In the books, Tom Bombadil didn't become invisible when wearing the ring.

Comment: That wasn't necessarily due to his race. I mean, it could be, but we have no idea what he was. His own intrinsic magic and or willpower was simply stronger than the power of the Ring, and it was unable to affect him. That may or may not have anything to do with his race.

Comment: @WOPR completely forgot about Tom (and me having read the book again recently, too)

Comment: I often try to forget Tom and his songs...

Comment: If we count the movies as canon, which I wouldn't in this particular instance, we have to remember that Gollum also puts on the Ring while he's falling into the lava in Mount Doom, _and doesn't become invisible_. That's obviously just for the viewers, though—it's hard to see the simultaneous signs of anguish and relief in the face of someone who's not there…

Answer (score 0):

My mental image is based on the movies rather than the book, but I always imagine Gollum as being naked, so this is a non-issue.  And a Ring that magically turns you invisible without making your clothes invisible as well is less useful/inconvenient than one that makes you and your clothes invisible.